# Select multiple rows in excel based on last row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code which selects the entire row from my table based on the last data in column K. E.g. if I have rows 5 to 10 populated, it will select row 10.

How do I get the code to select multiple rows from row 5 all the way to the last row as defined below?

Thanks

```
Sub selectlastrow()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim report As Worksheet
Set report = Excel.ActiveSheet

Sheets("Risks").Select

lastrow = Range("K5:K48").End(xlDown).Row

report.Cells(lastrow, 2).EntireRow.Select

End Sub
```

To follow up:

I'm stuck on how to structure a piece of code that:

1. Loops through all worksheets that begin with the number 673: (e.g. 673:green, 673:blue)
2. Selects the data in these worksheets from row 5 up until the last row with data - code that works for this is

   ```
   With report
   .Range(.Cells(5, "K"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Select
   End With
   ```
3. Select the "Colours" worksheet
4. Paste the rows at the next available blank row. There could be up to 40/50 worksheets which will have data pasted into the "Colours" worksheet so I need the data added to the next available line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: fwiw, when you say *' the last data in column K'*, it is better to look from the bottom up then from the top down.

Comment: FYI - It's best practice to [avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). I recommend reading through that, to learn how to work directly with your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cell reference that combines both the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx).

```
with report
     .Range(.Cells(5, "K"), .Cells(.rows.count, "K").End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Select
end with
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple ways to select a range of rows.  Easiest based on available data you have:

```
report.Range("K5").resize(lastrow - 4).EntireRow.Select
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Report.Range("B5:B" & lastrow).EntireRow.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're actually doing with your code, just replace the expression inside of `rowRange`.

```
Dim rowRange As Range
Set rowRange = Range("a1:A8").Rows.EntireRow
rowRange.Select
```

Voila!